# Finding a pdf of an exponential distribution

Tags: density-function

Random variable $X$ is distributed exponentially with mean 1. 
Find the pdf of $Y=(X-1)^2$

I'm not quite sure what this question is asking. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Please tell if this is homework.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is homework, so I'll just outline the answer.

This is about transformations of pdfs. You know the distribution of the variable $X$, which is exponential. Exponential distributions have only one parameter, which you'll have to determine backwards from the mean value.

Then you transform the distribution $X \longrightarrow Y(X)$. If you do the calculation, then you'll yield a pdf for Y.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by using the definition of $Y$ to compute the cdf of $Y$. Let $t\geq 0$. Then:

\begin{align}
F_Y(t) &=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq t)\\
&=\mathbb{P}((X-1)^2\leq t)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(\vert X-1\vert \leq \sqrt{t})\\
&=\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{t}\leq X-1\leq\sqrt{t})\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X\leq1+\sqrt{t})-\mathbb{P}(X\leq1-\sqrt{t})\\
&=1-\exp(-(1+\sqrt{t}))-(1-\exp(-(1-\sqrt{t})))\chi_{\{1\geq\sqrt{t}\}}\\
&=\begin{cases}
0,&t\leq 0\\
\exp(\sqrt{t}-1)-\exp(-\sqrt{t}-1),&t\in(0,1)\\
1-\exp(-\sqrt{t}-1),&t\geq 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}

To get the pdf of $Y$ you must differentiate this w.r.t. $t$, i.e.

$$
f_y(t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F_Y(t)=\begin{cases}
0,&t\leq 0\\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\left(\exp(\sqrt{t}-1)+\exp(-\sqrt{t}-1)\right),&t\in(0,1)\\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\exp(-\sqrt{t}-1),&t\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Please bear in mind we treat exercises a bit differently from other questions, giving hints rather than fully worked-out answers. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info.

Comment: I'm sorry,  wasn't aware of this!

Comment: No problem - I think most of us have found out this way!